# RecyclerView with StaggeredLayoutManager on multiple (difference) row and column span

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, staggeredgridlayout

i have a `RecyclerView` and `StaggeredLayoutManager` that i want to put some `CardView` with different row and column span but base on defined fixed size 

 like as it :

[image]

if you saw `CardView` of `0` is 4X (2 row x 2 column ) of `1`  
and smaller `CardView` size is base of other size

all card dimensions are :

Row X Column
1  x  1
1  x  2
2  x  1
2  x  2
but when i defined the `StaggeredLayoutManager` needs to pass span size  , in this case span size is `5` 
but main problem is when i pass span size my `RecyclerView` is divided by it and can not to handle more than 1 span and if that was bigger i see it is cut by half in width but height is ok

how can i to configure my `RecyclerView` or `StaggeredLayoutManager` to fix this problem and could to handle 2D span size in Row and Column both?